# Client side validation for custom annotation Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am referring this article:

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx

which shows how to create custom annotation in Asp.Net MVC 2. However, the client side validation scripts, especially "MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation" is not available in Asp.Net MVC4. I read it on one article it is part of Asp.Net Futures project. I want to hook up my client side validation using Jquery. In my project template script's folder, I see scripts named:

```
jquery.validate.min.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
```

Is there any way I can make use of these existing scripts? or do I have to compulsorily download futures project?

Comment: Google "MVC 3 custom validation" and you'll find several articles like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation_topic3 and http://tdryan.blogspot.com/2010/12/aspnet-mvc-3-custom-validation.html

Comment: @RickAndMSFT: This is what happens when you blindly post links on questions you didn't read. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation_topic3 is not about Jquery validation. It uses MicrosoftMvcValidation.js for client side validation which I don't want as I clearly stated in question and http://tdryan.blogspot.in/2010/12/aspnet-mvc-3-custom-validation.html uses built in RegularExpressionAttribute which automatically generates client side script. I am not using RegularExpressionAttribute. Based on your links I better not google :D

Comment: read the response below any my tutorials. It's not difficult to update them for MVC 4. The concepts are the same.

Comment: @TimTom no need to sound rude in your comment to Rick. He took the time to reply to your question, even if you you feel it wasnt the correct answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That article is specific to MVC 2 which used MicrosoftAjax. MVC 4 no longer includes the MS Ajax files as they have been deprecated and the preferred method is to use jquery.

To verify your settings, make sure these scripts are in your layout

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And these two settings are present in the appSettings section in your web.config file

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

So when you add data annotations to your ViewModels you get client side and server side validation both

```
public class MyModel 
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In your view just make sure you have code like this

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName) <br/>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName) <br/>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
</div>
```

**Update**

Here's an example of a custom validator that I have called RateRequiredIfCustomIndexRate
This is the javascript side of it so that it gets added to jquery validation

```
$("document").ready(function () {

    var isCustomRateRequired = document.getElementById("IsCustomRateRequired");

    isCustomRateRequired.onchange = function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#Rate').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#Rate').val('');
        }
        else {
            $('#Rate').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    };
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("raterequiredifcustomindexrate", function (value, element, param) {
    var rateRequired = $("#CustomRateRequired").val();
    if (rateRequired && value == "") {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("raterequiredifcustomindexrate");
```

Comment: So how do I hook up my client validation with these scripts? Any tutorial? article?

Comment: That's easy, you get it for free :-) when you decorate your ViewModel classes with data annotations, those same rules get translated to client side rules.. updating my answer now

Comment: Is that really possible? This is my custom validation annotation. I have extended using ***ValidationAttribute*** How does my C# code server side validation get translated automatically to Jquery language? I am curious.

Comment: Custom validation is different, you also have to add that custom validator to the jquery validation... updating answer again...

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. The article that I posted in my question is about custom validation not these built in types.

Comment: Basically, you add the rule to the validator and the error message will get shown. In my case, I am also enabling/disabling a field based in the rule result.

Answer (score 11):

The key thing missing here is that the server-side validator must implement the IClientValidatable interface:

```
public class RateRequiredIfCustomIndexRateAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = "raterequiredifcustomindexrate"
        };
    }
}
```

Once you do that, the client-side validation should be hooked up properly. You can verify this by making sure that your input field has an attribute "data-val-raterequiredifcustomindexrate" attribute.