# DataAnnotation Regular Expression not working

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to code a web app using ASP.NET which takes a numeric currency value in a web form and later displays the value as in a summary sheet.

I have been having a issue where no matter what validation I place in the Model I am still able to enter letters and special symbols which the user should be blocked from using straight away on the webform.

I am using the below code in my model and based on it I do not see how I am still able to enter non numeric values.

```
[Numeric]
[Min(1, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid number")]
[Required] 
public Double GoalAmount { get; set; }
```

Is there any change I could make?

The view looks like this.

```
        @model WebUI.Models.CreateFundModel
 @{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
  }
<div id="container_demo" >
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="login" class="animate form">
         @using (Html.BeginForm()){

             @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
             @Html.ValidationSummary()

           <h1>Create Fund</h1>
            <p>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
            </p>
            <p>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GoalAmount)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GoalAmount)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.GoalAmount)
            </p>
            <p>

                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ReleaseOn)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ReleaseOn)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ReleaseOn)
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#date").datepicker({
                            showAnim: 'slideDown',
                            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            </p>
             <p>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Frequency)                
                @Html.DropDownList("Frequency", string.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Frequency)
             </p>
             <p>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RecipiantAccount)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RecipiantAccount)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RecipiantAccount)
             </p>
            <p class="login button">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>

             @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")

         }
       </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This validation happens server side, have you configured your mvc application to use Client side validation?

See [the section "Enabling Client-Side Validation"](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript)

also see [Client side validation for custom annotation Asp.Net MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666045/client-side-validation-for-custom-annotation-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: I created a registration sheet which has has a email validator field done in much the same way. Once a user is logged in should I switch to client side validation.         [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter your Email")]
        [RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+",
            ErrorMessage= "Please Enter a valid Email Address")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

Comment: The best is always to validate server side first. Client side validation has some disadvantages, for example people can disable javascript, so it should not always be relied on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [DataAnnotationsExtension](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/). It has some useful attributes that you can use.

Comment: Thanks A Million. I have implemented this and tested it by changing my email login to use the data annotations extension {emailAddress] but still when I use [Numeric] it allows me to proceed entering a string into the text box. It has me really confused.

Comment: can you edit your earlier question so that we can see the update on what you did? :)

Comment: I've updated it now. It corresponds to scotts blog http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2011/02/23/introducing-data-annotations-extensions.aspx